# External Data in SharePoint online modern

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-search, microsoft-graph

How to get External Data into SharePoint online?

- What are the possible ways to get the external data using api and show the data in Search

How to show external data in SharePoint Search?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Graph connectors allow you to connect data sources to Microsoft Search. Here's a list of Graph connectors by Microsoft:

- Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2
- Azure DevOps
- Azure SQL and Microsoft SQL Server
- Enterprise websites
- MediaWiki
- File share
- Oracle SQL (preview)
- Salesforce (preview)
- ServiceNow

[Overview of Microsoft Graph connectors](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftsearch/connectors-overview#what-data-sources-can-be-connected-to-microsoft-search)

Comment: My data source is power dms. There is no connector, if I try to build custom connector  
  1.How can I achieve that the external data is continuously pushed to the MS Search Index? Do I have to implement it all on my own?

Comment: If the data is stored in an Azure SQL, MS SQL Server or Oracle SQL database then you could get the data directly using one of the connectors above. If not, you will need to create your own connector.